# why won't matches update in foreach loop in powershell

Tags: regex, loops, powershell, casting

I'm a novice powershell coder. I'm trying to get a list of strings of all my PCs. Like this:

> Win-PC-01
>
> Win-PC-02

Based off of AD names. With the following code I got the objects and then attempted to produce a list of strings to standard output. Instead it repeats the same string over and over like `$matches['content']` does not change in the loop.

1. Why wouldn't content be updated through each pass of the loop?
2. Is there a better way.

Code:

```
$a_computername = '*'
$a_os = "Windows 7*"
$a_os = '*'
$a_pcs = Get-ADComputer -Filter {
    (Name -like $a_computername) -and (OperatingSystem -like $a_os ) -and (Enabled -eq $true)
    } -Property * 

$a_pcs.count
foreach ($i in $a_pcs) {
    $ms = $i | Format-List Name
    $ms -match "Name : (?<content>.*)"
    $Matches['content']
}
```

Comment: `Format-List Name` will not give you a consistent output.  `$Matches` holds the last match until it finds something new.

Answer (score 3):

does something simple like

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem | ? {$_.OperatingSystem -match "Windows 10" -and $_.Enabled} | Select -Expand Name
```

work for you?

Comment: The $_.OperatingSystem returns nothing for me when I grab a comptuer from Ad. `Get-ADComputer "computername" | Select -Property OperatingSystem` ... is the property name different?

Comment: @CoryEtmund forgot to include `-Properties` sorry about that! should work now?

Comment: You should escape your space in `-match 'Windows\s10'`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 why would I need to? regex will see it as a literal space? regardless it's just an example string.

Comment: @ConnorLSW It's a best practice to do so.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 isn't the back tick `` the escape character for powershell?

Comment: I didn't use a grave accent.